# Spawning objects in animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to make a conveyor that drops parts into a box. Is there a way to spawn an object on the conveyor on a timed system so that it can fill the box? I've looked all over and could not find the direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Frame X-1: set the object position outside the screen, Frame X: move the object into the screen
- Use an emitter to emit the parts (with the number of emissions you can control the frequency of emission) (see image 1)
- You can have all the objects invisible and animate the visibility in the timeline using the shader

image 1:

[image]